# How to access Alfresco database?

Tags: alfresco

I would like to know if there's a way to connect to or see the database behind alfresco community.

Is there any way to access alfresco database?

Comment: What do you mean ? Are you using the default database with alfresco ?

Comment: Yes! I'm using the default database and I want to be able to see the tables structures and so on,
And my own web app to connect with alfresco default database and to send requests to it

Comment: Then Lutz answer is the good one.

Comment: Hint: If you think an answer solved your problem you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark next to the vote arrows. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I've already did that but they say that my reputation doesn't allow my vote to change the score

Answer (score 2):

The information necessary to connect to the database is stored in the file

```
tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties
```

in your Alfresco installation directory. The relevant configuration looks like this (for PostgreSQL):

```
### database connection properties ###
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.username=alfresco
db.password=secret*password
db.name=alfresco
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/alfresco
```

This allows you to connect to the PostgreSQL database using a a client of your choice.

**Edit:** The Alfresco database is highly normalized. Some tables to start at are:

- `alf_store`
- `alf_node`
- `alf_node_properties`

There are many foreign key constraints that reference other columns, for example:

- `alf_node.store_id` references `alf_store.id`
- `alf_node_properties.node_id` references `alf_node.id`

If you want to get specific data from the database and don't know how, please ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you!
I see, but how can i have an idea about the database structure to know what I'm dealing with.
that's my question